# Get details of Peoplepicker field from another list in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am having a functionality in a custome form where if I select a Resource name (people picker column), the remaining EmpID, 
Projects and Manager columns has to filled. All these columns are in a list named "EmpDetails".
I tried using CAML query but couldn't succed. This is my code:

```
<tr class="container">
 <div id="container">
    <table id="table">
       <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Resource Name</th>
          <th>EmpID</th>
          <th>Projects</th>
          <th>Manager</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
       </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><span id="resourcename"></span></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtempid" placeholder="Emp ID"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtprojects" placeholder="Projects"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtreportmgr" placeholder="Reporting Manager"/></td>
          <td><input type="button" id="delrow" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/> </td>
          <td><input type="button" id="addrow" value="+" onclick="addRow()"/> </td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
</tr>
```

Javascript code:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        ConvertoToRequestPeoplePicker('resourcename');
       BindData(); 


    });
     function BindData()
{
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        LoadingMessage();
        SPLoaded();
    });
}
function SPLoaded()
{
try
{
    var resourceInfoList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('EmpDetails');
    var resourceInfoQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    resourceInfoQuery.set_viewXml(  '<View>' +
                                        '<ViewFields>' +
                                            '<FieldRef Name=\'EmpID\' />' +
                                            '<FieldRef Name=\'Projects\' />' +
                                            '<FieldRef Name=\'Manager\' />' +
                                        '</ViewFields>' +
                                        '<Query>' +
                                            '<Where>' +
                                                '<Value  Type="User">' + itm.get_item("Employee").get_lookupId() + '</Value>'+
                                            '</Where>' +
                                            '<OrderBy>' +
                                                '<FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="TRUE" />' +
                                            '</OrderBy>' +
                                        '</Query>' +
                                    '</View>');
    var resourceInfoListItems = resourceInfoList.getItems(resourceInfoQuery);
    context.load(resourceInfoListItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(null, LoadConfigurationValues), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, arg) { alert("Error in getLoginUser : " + arg.get_message()); waitDialogLoad.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); }));

}
   catch(ex)
    {
        alert("Something went wrong : "+ex.message);
        waitDialogLoad.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
    }
}
```

I am beginner in SharePoint and got the above code from some site. I couldn't whether this is correct code or no. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your CAML-query isn't valid... 
the 'Where'-part of such a query must be formed like:

```
<Where>
    <compareOperator>
        <Value/>
        <FieldRef/>
    </compareOperator>
</Where>
```

the compareOperator is usually something like "Eq", "Lt" etc.
the value usually gets a type attribute and the fieldref is defining which field in a list (or library) item should be compared to the value in the query.

putting all that together we get an example like:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
                <Value Type='Number'>1</Value>/Geq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

For a more in-depth look you can check out the [sp jsom how-to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) ;>